# Why does the cleanup.policy of the topic __consumer_offsets is COMPACT?

Tags: apache-kafka

Why that topic is COMPACT and not, for example, DELETE+COMPACT?

Is there a specific reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because, If you run a group consumer, and it stops for some time, After restating group consumer, it should consume from last offset it is consumed.

`__consumer_offsets` topics keeps your group consumer's last offset for each partition it is consumed. So if it deleted from the kafka, there is no trace for that.

`cleanup.policy = compact` means it will keep the latest message for a key any long untill you tomstone it.

So, like this, your grouo consumer's last offset is secured in `__consumer.offsets` because it is compacted.